Tensor Product of a vector space with itself.
I've been reading up on tensor products and have been coming up blank on how to think about $V \otimes_F V$, where $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$.
I only care about what is happening when $\dim(V)=1$ since I'm working with line bundles at the moment but higher dimensions would also be helpful.
Letting $V$ be spanned by some $a$, then we should get that $V \otimes_F V$ is spanned by $a \otimes a$, something one dimensional. This leads me to believe that $V \otimes_F V \simeq V$.
Doing the quotient space construction yields that $V \otimes_F V \simeq (V \times V)/\sim$. Working this out also gives a one dimensional vector space.
This also makes me wonder what $V^{\otimes m}$ should be. I saw an eample that $\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \mathbb{R}^2$ is spanned by four elements. so my intuition tells me it is similar to $\mathbb{R}^4$. Is my intuition on theright path?

In the case of one dimensional vector spaces indeed $V\cong \mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F}\otimes_\mathbb{F}\mathbb{F}\cong\mathbb{F}$. Vector spaces are isomorphic if they have the same dimension and the dimension of the tensor product is the product of the dimensions so you are correct in saying that $\mathbb{R}^2\otimes \mathbb{R}^2\cong \mathbb{R}^4$.

I don't think the one-dimensional case is the best thing to think about to gain intuition, because it's a little too simple.

Be careful. The quotient construction most assuredly does not start with $V\times V$. (For one thing, if $V$ is $n$-dimensional, an $n^2$-dimensional vector space has trouble being a quotient of a $2n$-dimensional vector space.)

I actually think the 1d case is quite instructive to study first.

If you want to think about line bundles you need to be careful here. It is true that dimension is multiplicative with respect to tensor product, so we always have
$$\dim V \otimes W = \dim V \dim W.$$
In particular if $V$ and $W$ are both $1$-dimensional then so is $V \otimes W$, and hence if $V$ is $1$-dimensional then so is $V^{\otimes n}$. This continues to be true for line bundles: tensor products of line bundles remain line bundles, and so tensor powers of line bundles remain line bundles.
To prove this you prove that if $\{ v_i \}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{ w_j \}$ is a basis of $W$ then $\{ v_i \otimes w_j \}$ is a basis of $V \otimes W$. This means if $V, W$ are both $1$-dimensional with bases $v, w$ (here a basis is just any nonzero vector) then $V \otimes W$ is $1$-dimensional with basis $v \otimes w$.
However, we do not have $V \otimes V \cong V$ in the context of line bundles. $V \otimes V$ is a different, non-isomorphic line bundle in general. What this means is that even in the case of ordinary vector spaces we don't have a natural isomorphism $V \otimes V \cong V$; to produce such an isomorphism we have to choose a basis of $V$, which may seem like a harmless choice but in the context of line bundles this choice needs to be made continuously and that can be done iff $V$ is trivializable.
The simplest example here is the unique nontrivial real line bundle $L$ over the circle $S^1$, whose total space is an open Möbius strip. This line bundle $L$ is nontrivial; it "twists" as you go around the circle. However, $L \otimes L$ (which "twists twice") is trivial (and this is true more generally for any real line bundle); you can visualize the total space as a Möbius strip with two twists, to really see very concretely how this ends up being the same thing as zero twists.

Qiaochu's answer is great, especially addressing the issue of choosing a basis for line bundles. Here's the general story for constructing tensor products of vector spaces and one convenient basis: the monomial basis.

For vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ with bases $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$ and $\{w_1, \dots, w_n\}$, the collection
$$
\begin{matrix}
v_1 \otimes w_1 & v_1 \otimes w_2 & \cdots & v_1 \otimes w_n \\
v_2 \otimes w_1 & v_2 \otimes w_2 & \cdots & v_2 \otimes w_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
v_m \otimes w_1 & v_m \otimes w_2 & \cdots & v_m \otimes w_n
\end{matrix}
$$
forms a basis of $V \otimes W$ so that dimensions behave like $\dim(V \otimes W) = (\dim V)(\dim W)$.
Of course, these constructions can be iterated to form the tensor power $V^{\otimes r} = \underbrace{V \otimes \cdots \otimes V}_{r\text{ 
 factors}}$ with basis
$$
\bigl\{ v_I = v_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_r} \bigm| I \in \{1, \ldots, n\}^r \bigr\}.
$$
The notation $I = (i_1, \ldots, i_r)$ gathers up the indices in each tensor factor to form a multi-index. It's a straightforward exercise in counting to see that $\dim(V^{\otimes r}) = (\dim V)^r$.
Of course all of these constructions play really nicely with the direct sum, and together the pair $(\oplus, \otimes)$ interact in the category of vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ in analogous ways to the pair $(+, \cdot\,)$ in the natural numbers. And this connection is made explicit by considering dimensions. For example, the natural isomorphism
$$
U \otimes (V \oplus W) \cong (U \otimes V) \oplus (U \otimes W), 
$$
has a dimensional "shadow"
$$
(\dim U)(\dim V + \dim W) = (\dim U)(\dim V) + (\dim U)(\dim W).
$$
